# Is there an Appcelerator Titanium repository like Cocoa Controls?

Tags: web, cross-platform, titanium, appcelerator

I'm looking for repository for Appcelerator Titanium Sample Apps like [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com) for iOS.

Is there any other Websites similar to Cocoa Controls for Titanium?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could use Titanium Kitchen Sink. But a complete site with samples is not known to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[88 Titanium Appcelerator Apps Based Open Source Projects](http://maran-emil.de/nodes/88-titanium-appcelerator-apps-based-open-source-projects)